# Does oxygen have the power to heal people?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, medicine, oxygen

I have come to notice that oxygen is used in medicine (hyperbaric chamber) to support fast recovery of bone's fractures, wounds and even cancer.

Moreover, according some studies and publications insects were bigger in the far past of our planet due to the increse percentage of oxygen at about 30%

My questions are:

- May we definitevely say as a fact ascertained by science that oxygen has the power to heal people?
- What was, in recorded history, the maximum length of time a person has spent in enriched oxygen enviroment and what are the conclusions reported after the experiment?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for healthStackexchange. It has no worldbuilding

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Brix*! I am sorry, but I fail to see how you are building your own world here. It looks like this is a question about the real world. You might be better off asking on a site dedicated to provide this sort of information, like Biology.StackExchange. Be sure to include links to the studies you mention when you are asking there, so people can point out facts/problems with those. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about this site and visit those links on the other sites as well. Have fun on the SE-network!

Comment: Nothing has "the power to heal people". There is no "healing power" in the real world. There are just certain substances you need to consume for your body to function properly or can help in certain situations given certain symptoms. Oxygen is great overall, I would advice breathing it, but it's not magical.

Comment: Too much oxygen is definitely not beneficial... it is outright dangerous. Wikipedia has an extensive page on [Oxygen toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity). And no, Oxygen does not "have the power to heal people". Living tissue heals itself. Some substances and/or treatments can assist the self-healing by aiding the healing process or by keeping things that would harm the healing process at bay.

Comment: This might also be a question for skeptics.stackexchange.com